# When does a fused-head NP require a definite determiner?

Tags: definite-articles, noun-phrases

In section **9.3 Fusion of internal modifier and head**, *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (Page 417) says:

> **(d) Modifiers denoting colour, provenance, and composition**
>
> [25] i Henrietta likes red shirts, and I like [**blue**].
>
> ii Knut wanted the purple wallpaper, but I wanted [the **mauve**].
>
> iii Henrietta likes Russian vodka, and I like [**Polish**].
>
> iv Knut wanted the French caterers, but I wanted [the **Italian**].
>
> v I prefer cotton shirts to [**nylon**].
>
> vi Knut likes malt whisky, but I prefer [**blended**].
>
> The NPs here are either bare or have a definite determiner;...

It seems that only [ii] and [iv] have 'the' in the bracket because only their preceding NPs have 'the' in 'the purple wallpaper' and 'the French caterers'.

If appropriate context is provided, can you put 'the' in other examples and remove 'the' in [ii] and [iv] as follows?

> [25a] i Henrietta likes red shirts, and I like [the **blue**].
>
> ii Knut wanted the purple wallpaper, but I wanted [**mauve**].
>
> iii Henrietta likes Russian vodka, and I like [the **Polish**].
>
> iv Knut wanted the French caterers, but I wanted [**Italian**].
>
> v I prefer cotton shirts to [the **nylon**].
>
> vi Knut likes malt whisky, but I prefer [the **blended**].

Comment: No, you can't.  I mean, you could, but if you do, you change the meaning.  If, for example, you take "the" out before "mauve," it means that you wanted mauve wallpaper (not any particular mauve wallpaper but just any mauve wallpaper) instead of that specific blue wallpaper that Knut wanted. When you say "the" before mauve, you're saying there were two wallpapers, one blue and one mauve, and you wanted the one that was Mauve, while Knut wanted the one that was blue.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman So the use of "the" is entirely dependent on the context, and is not automatically determined by whether the preceding NP also has "the". Right?

Comment: Sort of.  The preceding nounphrase isn't excluded from the context.

Comment: Think of it this way. There's nothing special or new in this specific case. The definite article **still** performs the same function as always. Applying that, it is easy to see why we need to or should not use the definite article in a given instance. HTH.

Comment: 'Knut likes malt whisky, but I prefer the blended' sounds infelicitous to my ears. There's a mismatch. 'Knut likes the malt whisky, but I prefer blended' is also unbalanced,  but doesn't sound as unnatural. It would be used where the malt whisky involved is identified, but _blended_ is stated in general terms (and imprecisely; there are some blends I've tasted that I'm sure the speaker would also refuse).

Comment: FYI--NP is *noun phrase*, if anyone is unfamiliar.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is based on my own grammaticality judgements, not on any theory. Syntactically, it seems possible to either use the definite article or leave it out. The phrases have different meanings, just like "red shirts" and "the red shirts" are both syntactically valid noun phrases with different meanings. For many of the sentences you list, I can't imagine an "appropriate context" for switching around the definite article usage. If the article (or lack of it) sounds wrong in a version of the sentence where the noun is repeated, then it would I think also sound wrong in the version of the sentence with the "fused head NP" construction. Just see how the following sentences sound:

> [25a] *i* Henrietta likes red shirts, and I like [the blue shirts].

This is technically a possible sentence, but in most contexts it would be very strange. It means that Henrietta likes "red shirts" (generic shirts of this type), while I like "the blue shirts" (some specific group of blue shirts). If you could say this, you could also say "...and I like the blue" in a context where you'd previously mentioned the blue shirts.

You could go through the same procedure for the rest of the sentences; e.g.

> *ii* Knut wanted the purple wallpaper, but I wanted [mauve wallpaper]

doesn't actually seem that bad, in that it might be said when there is a specific purple wallpaper that Knut wants, but I don't have any specific mauve wallpaper in mind (I just know that I like mauve wallpaper in general). So likewise, "Knut wanted the purple wallpaper, but I wanted mauve" doesn't sound particularly odd to me.

I won't actually go through all the rest. The use of "the" or not is based on the meaning; in most cases, the appropriate article will be the same for the two phrases, but it isn't just a matter of mechanically copying the article of the preceding noun phrase.

Comment: I am trying to figure out if noun phrases that are introduced with determiners or Quantifiers (like some of the money) are D phrases with a Q phrase moved to the specifier place or Q phrases that take PPs complements. I got several examples from books but it is still not making sense to me.

Answer (score -2):

From the comments

> … If, for example, you take "the" out before "mauve," it means that you wanted mauve wallpaper (not any particular mauve wallpaper but just any mauve wallpaper) instead of that specific blue wallpaper that Knut wanted. … - @BenjaminHarman

This is basically correct, but the variant with "the" does not necessarily exclude any other mauve wallpaper, only the blue wallpaper in question. Vice Versa, leaving out the definite article does not exclude the specific mauve wallpaper, but we are not told about it. In effect, the context dependence is a matter of discourse, not grammar.

Grammatically, if there had been no blue or mauve mentioned, as far as the context of your written example goes, there would be no definite wallpaper. Likewise, If I said just now "I like the cheese", the article would be meaningless. Vice Versa, if I say "I like cheese", I might still hold Cheddar to be rejectable at my own discretion. "_ cheese" is indefinite.

In discourse however, it opens up a context for inquiry that is easily fullfilled in your example. Tom wants the blue paper that he wants, I like the cheese that I like and longcat is long. Doesn't that seem non-sensical, though? Rather, the example implies that *the blue wallpaper* was introduced in a previous sentence, and a speaker might just hold us liable if we missed, e.g. because we weren't with them in the shop, so to speak. That is, "have you seen *the* big cat" is not opinionated, and "yesterday I talked to *that* man." - "which man?" likewise opens a new context, all the same as "yesterday I talked to a man" does (while *the man* might imply the big cheese, or any man known from context), but "have you seen a big cat?" is ambiguous and only "any cat" is really general, though you might still not want to hear about lions.

As far as syntax is concerned, the previous examples are equivalent. They only differ by semantics (which some might push down into syntactic notation but that's a different matter). However complete omission, "have you seen cat", implies a title, a proper noun or name. "He invited Bob, but I wanted Alice". "mauve" as a categorical term is well amendable to work as a title. In a long discussion it would be a matter of speech economics to leave out the article, "now which is it, mauve or blue?". Although, I guess "mauve or blue" would be more likely, laying stress on blue as the preferable choice.

There remains the matter of "the blue *one*", which I'll ignore for now.

Comment: How is that only "basically correct"?  What you say after "but" is the same exact thing I said only in different words.  What's more, what you say next is wrong.  If you leave out "the" before "mauve," there's no specific mauve wallpaper at all, so it can't be not excluded.  If we're not told about it, then it's not specified, ergo no specific mauve wallpaper exists to exclude or not exclude.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman the problem is where you wrote "not any particular mauve wallpaper". This is ambiguous between *not have a particular wallpaper* and *have a not particular wallpaper*. Of course "no particular" is idiomatic, and I tried to point out the consequences of the necessary underspecification, that is not to be confused with ambiguity. This is not easy, but not unexplicable either. However, when you say "no specific mauve wallpaper exists ..." you are not explaining anything, you are just using the same idiom. It's circular reasoning, but I want it straight.